# Calling a method from another class with setters and getters in Java

Tags: java, class, variables, object, methods

I need some help with this as I'm completely lost. I'm trying to call a method I created in another class to output what the grade is for the average entered by the user, but I'm not sure where I messed up. I don't get how to call my other class, I read that using an object as a variable doesn't work in Java, but I have no clue how else to get it to pull through to apply the method in the other class to give the correct grade.

Here's the class that contains the method....

```
public class Assignment {

    private double score;

    public double getScore(){
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(double newScore){
        score = newScore;
    }

    public static void newScore(double a, double b, double c, double d, double f) {

        double score1 = a;
        double score2 = b;
        double score3 = c;
        double score4 = d;
        double score5 = f;

        if (score1 >= 90) {
            System.out.println("Your grade is: " + score1);
            System.out.println("Great job!");
        } else if (score2 >= 80 && score2 < 90) {
            System.out.println("Your grade is: " + score2);
            System.out.println("Not bad!");
        } else if (score3 >= 70 && score3 < 80) {
            System.out.println("Your grade is: " + score3);
            System.out.println("Need a little work");
        } else if (score4 >= 60 && score4 < 70) {
            System.out.println("Your grade is: " + score4);
            System.out.println("Not looking so good.");
        } else if (score5 >= 50 && score5 < 60) {
            System.out.println("Your grade is: " + score5);
            System.out.print("Study harder!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Yikes!");
        }
    }
}
```

And here's what I put in the main method...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grades {

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Assignment newScore = new Assignment ();    
        System.out.println("Enter your test score: ");
        newScore = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Your current grade is: " + newScore);       
    }

}
```

Comment: You havent set the score att all

Comment: Which method do you want to call? And `Assignment.newScore(1,2,3,4,5);`

Comment: newScore is an Object you cannot assign it to int

Comment: So how would I need to put it to pull through what I have in the method newScore? I don't get how to pull through what the grade is supposed to be after the user enters his score. We're supposed to create the variable private score; and create setters and getters for it, do I need to create a getter and setter for each individual grade?

Answer (score 0):

Since the variable `newScore` is a `Assignment` object rather than a `double`, the code `newScore = input.nextDouble();` can not be compiled. I suppose you are using the input number as your `score`, so that line should be

`newScore.setScore(input.nextDouble());`

Hence the next line should be

`System.out.println("Your current grade is: " + newScore.getScore());`

Kindly replace these two lines and check if it suites your requirements.

EDIT:

`Assignment.java`:

```
public class Assignment {

    private double score;

    public double getScore(){
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(double newScore){
        score = newScore;
    }

    public void checkScore(double a, double b, double c, double d, double f) {
        if (score >= a) {
            System.out.println("Your grade is: " + score);
            System.out.println("Great job!");
        } else if (score >= b && score < a) {
            System.out.println("Your grade is: " + score);
            System.out.println("Not bad!");
        } else if (score >= c && score < b) {
            System.out.println("Your grade is: " + score);
            System.out.println("Need a little work");
        } else if (score >= d && score < c) {
            System.out.println("Your grade is: " + score);
            System.out.println("Not looking so good.");
        } else if (score >= f && score < d) {
            System.out.println("Your grade is: " + score);
            System.out.print("Study harder!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Yikes!");
        }
    }
}
```

`Grades.java`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grades {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Assignment newScore = new Assignment();
        System.out.println("Enter your test score: ");
        newScore.setScore(input.nextDouble());
        newScore.checkScore(90, 80, 70, 60, 50);
        System.out.println("Your current grade is: " + newScore.getScore());
    }

}
```

Comment: It got rid of the errors, but didn't pull through what I was looking for. We're supposed to be working with setters and getters on this assignment, and they asked to create a variable for private double score; then create setters and getters to hold the score, but then a method to say whether the grade is an a, b, c, d or f after the user enters his score. I'm just lost on how to pull that through exactly. I get how to use the setters and getters and set my own values for those, but not sure how to use it when you have multiple options to choose from.

Comment: I think your original method `newScore` should be used to check that the grade is an `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` or `f`, so I have modify that method. That method is used to determine which interval the score is located at, and the interval is determined by the parameters of that method. I have also add a test case of that method, where `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `f` are 90, 80, 70, 60, 50 respectively. Please try out the code I updated and let me your feedback. @Nooberistic

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite understand your question here. You have a method that takes in multiple score, and it has a set of if-else statements to determine the message to print based off;

if first score is more than 90 do this, 
and if first score's condition is not met, then check second score value.
and then if second condition not met, then check third score to see if it met certain score.. blah blah

If you are looking at having an assignment class to keep a set of scores and finally print out each score then do this;

Modify your Assignment class is to allow multiple scores to be kept at a time. To be able to hold multiple scores you will have to change the score variable to be at least an array or a list. That is, `List<Double> scores = new ArrayList<Double>();`

Then modify the setter method to be something like "addScore(double score)"

```
public void addScore(double score) {
    scores.add(score)
}
```

In your "newScore" method, use a loop to iterate through the score to output the appropriate score message for each assignment.

```
for (Double score : scores) {
    if (score > 90) {   
        System.out.println('blah');
    }
}
```

Note the code above are just something I type off my mind, I didn't test it using any compilers so you may have to rework on some syntax errors.

Comment: We're supposed to be working with setters and getters on this assignment, and they asked to create a variable for private double score; then create setters and getters to hold the score, but then a method to say whether the grade is an a, b, c, d or f after the user enters his score. I'm just lost on how to pull that through exactly. I get how to use the setters and getters and set my own values for those, but not sure how to use it when you have multiple options to choose from.